# WebForm CSS Styling - Radio Buttons

Tags: theming, webforms

Giving all of the other components are simple. However the radio button seems a bit challenging.  I've added class to the following

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"], .radio input[type="radio"], .radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
margin-left: -20px;
position: absolute;
```

however doesnt seem to work. I'm looking for an HTML5 style layout.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty difficult to help you here. Are you trying to make your radio buttons inline?

If you are using Bootstrap theme with everything else working right, according to: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp) you should be able to just name it class="radio-inline" and then target .radio-inline class in CSS with what you are trying to achieve.